# How to increase/check default memory Docker has on Linux?

Tags: linux, docker

I've seen that on Windows and Mac it's very easy to change the RAM containers are given - you just go into the GUI. But how do you do this on Linux, where it's a CLI instead of a GUI?

The Docker docs mention an `-m` flag, but this flag doesn't give any response (just prints the entirety of the help output again) so I don't know whether it worked. It also seems specific to containers, whereas I'd like to change the global default.

Lastly, is there a way to check the current default RAM, so I can make sure whatever I do in the end actually worked?

Comment: If you're using `docker-compose` you can limit resources consumed using the `ymal` config.

Answer (score 35):

On native Linux, Docker can use all available host memory.  It uses a lightweight kernel-based isolation mechanism that generally shares resources like CPU cores and memory (and on modern installations, disk space) using the standard kernel mechanism.  There isn't a control or setting to limit or increase this.

On other platforms Docker runs a hidden Linux VM to be able to run a Linux kernel to use these isolation mechanisms, and the Docker Desktop memory control affects the memory allocation for that VM.

Comment: I see! So what happens when I pass an argument using the `-m` flag on Linux?

Comment: It sets a memory limit on the cgroup managing the container.  It's not too dissimilar from the `ulimit` command, in that it sets a limit enforced by the kernel, but it doesn't specifically partition resources.

Comment: The GUI option to configure max resources is now also gone from Windows if you use WSL2.
But it can be configured in other ways - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405765/memory-allocation-to-docker-containers-after-moving-to-wsl-2-in-windows

Answer (score 15):

This is how I "check" the Docker container memory:

Open the linux command shell and -

**Step 1:** Check what containers are running.

`docker ps`

**Step 2:** Note down the 'CONTAINER ID' of the container you want to check and issue the following command:

`docker container stats <containerID>`

eg:

`docker container stats c981`

This will give an output like:

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
c981c9482284        registry            0.00%               4.219MiB / 1.944GiB   0.21%               9.66kB / 0B         0B / 0B             14
```

'MEM USAGE / LIMIT' column will give you the actual memory usage and default memory allocated.

Note : press ctrl+c to come out of the view and back to command prompt.

Comment: No, the question was how to CHANGE the memory, not how to view it.

Comment: @juergi There's a second question in the post, which means it should probably be closed for "needs focus."

Comment: @GeneralGrievance That is stupid. We are not allowed to ask 2 related questions anymore on stackoverflow?

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal You can. The "Ask Question" button is still available when you ask your first question.