# Increase docker engine memory on Unix

Tags: docker, unix

I run a docker build on my unix build machine and therefore I need more than 2GB Memory (default value of docker engine). I got the build working on my Mac with the docker Desktop UI in the settings as you can see it in the image.
[image]

How is this possible in Unix?

Comment: Should probably read [this from the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) (found by searching for "docker memory configuration"). See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/62649255

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the allocated memory and CPU while running a container you can try this:

```
docker run -it --cpus="2" --memory="4096m" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

You can also do the same while deploying services using `docker-compose`

More infos:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

[How to specify Memory & CPU limit in docker compose version 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345235/how-to-specify-memory-cpu-limit-in-docker-compose-version-3)

Comment: I need it running docker build instead of docker run.