# Unable to get OpenSearch dashboard by running OpenSearch docker compose

Tags: docker, server, localhost, windows-subsystem-for-linux, opensearch-dashboards

I am a windows user. I installed Windows Subsystem for Linux [wsl2] and then installed docker using it. Then I tried to get started with OpenSearch so I followed the documentation in the given link
https://opensearch.org/downloads.html and run docker-compose up, In the shell, I am getting an error message like

> opensearch-dashboards  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-01-18T16:31:18Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ConnectionError]: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN opensearch-node1 opensearch-node1:9200"}

In the port http://localhost:5601/ I am getting messages like

> OpenSearch Dashboards server is not ready yet

I also changed resources preference for memory to 5GB in docker-desktop but it still doesn't work. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 5 days having issues with opensearch I've found something working fine for me:

- Set docker memory to 4GB
- And docker vm.max_map_count = 262144

Then I use previous versions of opensearch because the latest does not seems stable:

- opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
- opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.1.0
- opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1A:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node1A
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1A
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # maximum number of open files for the OpenSearch user, set to at least 65536 on modern systems
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-node2A:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3
    container_name: opensearch-node2A
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2A
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=opensearch-node1A,opensearch-node2A
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboardsA:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.1.0
    container_name: opensearch-dashboardsA
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1A:9200","https://opensearch-node2A:9200"]'
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  logstash-with-plugin:
    image: opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2
    container_name: logstash-with-plugin
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
```

Comment: After falling into other problems I choose to use ELK stack because opensearch does not seems mature to me yet but I'll keep looking into it in the future

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when opening "http://localhost:5601/" while testing opensearch and opensearch dasboard locally using Docker in Windows 10:

- OpenSearch Dashboards server is not ready yet
- opensearch-dashboards |
  {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2022-02-10T12:29:35Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ConnectionError]:
  getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN opensearch-node1 opensearch-node1:9200"}

But when looking into the log I also found this other error:

- opensearch-node1 | [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

The 3 part solution working for me was:

**Part 1**

On each opensearch nodes update the file:

```
/usr/share/opensearch/config/opensearch.yml
```

And add line:

```
plugins.security.disabled: true
```

Before the security plugins:

```
cks. "Single-node" mode disables them again.
#discovery.type: single-node

plugins.security.disabled: true

######## Start OpenSearch Security Demo Configuration ########
# WARNING: revise all the lines below before you go into production
plugins.security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
```

I found the information on opensearch official [documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security-plugin/configuration/disable/)

**Part 2**

Setting allocated memory for docker desktop to 4GB into .wslconfig more information here:
[opendistrocommunity discussion](https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/the-best-way-in-order-to-see-this-product/6349/2)
[stackoverflow aloocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62405765/memory-allocation-to-docker-containers-after-moving-to-wsl-2-in-windows)

Make sure your allocated memory is well set up (you have to restart docker desktop) with this command: docker info and check the line "Total Memory" it should be set to 4GB (approximately, in my case it has be set to 3.84GiB)

**Part 3**

And also increase vm.max_map_count:

- open powershell
- wsl -d docker-desktop
- echo "vm.max_map_count = 262144" > /etc/sysctl.d/99-docker-desktop.conf

The info was founded [here on github discussion](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5202)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Opensearch-dashboards instance installed on VM without Docker usage. The problem was caused by wrong setting for connection to search engine in the `opensearch-dashboards.yml` file. I mixed up https and http protocols here (there was mismatch between settings of opensearch and opensearch-dashboards):

`opensearch.hosts: [https://localhost:9200]`

Answer (score 1):

As of Feb 1st 2024 the official docs work perfectly:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  opensearch-node1: # This is also the hostname of the container within the Docker network (i.e. https://opensearch-node1/)
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest # Specifying the latest available image - modify if you want a specific version
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster # Name the cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1 # Name the node that will run in this container
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # Nodes to look for when discovering the cluster
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # Nodes eligible to serve as cluster manager
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true # Disable JVM heap memory swapping
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # Set min and max JVM heap sizes to at least 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1 # Set memlock to unlimited (no soft or hard limit)
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536 # Maximum number of open files for the opensearch user - set to at least 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data1:/usr/share/opensearch/data # Creates volume called opensearch-data1 and mounts it to the container
    ports:
      - 9200:9200 # REST API
      - 9600:9600 # Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - opensearch-net # All of the containers will join the same Docker bridge network
  opensearch-node2:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:latest # This should be the same image used for opensearch-node1 to avoid issues
    container_name: opensearch-node2
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node2
      - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - opensearch-data2:/usr/share/opensearch/data
    networks:
      - opensearch-net
  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest # Make sure the version of opensearch-dashboards matches the version of opensearch installed on other nodes
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601 # Map host port 5601 to container port 5601
    expose:
      - "5601" # Expose port 5601 for web access to OpenSearch Dashboards
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://opensearch-node1:9200","https://opensearch-node2:9200"]' # Define the OpenSearch nodes that OpenSearch Dashboards will query
    networks:
      - opensearch-net

volumes:
  opensearch-data1:
  opensearch-data2:

networks:
  opensearch-net:
```

Then run `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

Incase if this helps some1,

I had no luck following official doc (especially with multi-nodes) and ended up setting it up manually with my limited Docker knowledge.

Below is my setup

- WSL2:Alpine#3.17.0 on Win 11
- Standard Docker Engine + Cli setup on WLS2:Alpine

opensearch:1.3.8 (single node) server setup

- run opensearch single node :

  `docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 9600:9600 -e "discovery.type=single-node" opensearchproject/opensearch:1.3.8`
- ensure its up & running

  `docker ps`
- ensure you are able to hit api with login creds,

defaults are `https://localhost:9200` uname: `admin` pass: `admin`

- inspect container to get Gateway :

  `docker inspect <containerName> or <containerId>` to grab `NetworkSettings`.`Gateway` property, note it down somewhere, will be required to setup opensearch-dashboard. For me it was something like `172.17.117.1`

opensearch-dashboard:1.3.8 setup

- create a custom `custom-opensearch-dashboards.yml` file somewhere in your WLS2 home directory with below contents

```
server.host: '0.0.0.0'
server.port: 5601
opensearch.hosts: [https://yourGatewayIpHere:9200]
opensearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
opensearch.username: uiuser1
opensearch.password: uipass1
opensearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [authorization, securitytenant]
opensearch_security.multitenancy.enabled: false
opensearch_security.multitenancy.tenants.preferred: [Private, Global]
opensearch_security.readonly_mode.roles: [kibana_read_only]
opensearch_security.cookie.secure: false
```

- pull opensearch-dashboards image :

  `docker pull opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:1.3.8`
- run opensearch-dashboards with customized config:

  `docker run -d -p 5601:5601 -v /fullPath/of/custom-opensearch-dashboards.yml:/usr/share/opensearch-dashboards/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml`
- ensure its up & running

  `docker ps`
- on your browser see if you can load `http://localhost:5601/` and log in with `opensearch.username` `opensearch.password` creds

Other useful Docker commands

- view logs

  `docker logs <containerName> or <containerId>`
- sh to container to check config or ping required apis :

  `docker exec -it <containerName> or <containerId> sh`

Good luck !