WSL 2 memory allocation with Docker
I am using WSL2 with Docker (v4.29.0) and I am experiencing memory problems, at first VmmemWSL process was taking something like 20GB of my memory, so I added the following line in my .wslconfig file to limite the memory used by WSL: memory=8GB.
I can see in Docker that it is working fine:

But then, as soon as I'm interacting with my containers, the memory goes up, slowly but surely, until it reaches the maximum I set and then I have to restart Docker since my containers don't repond anymore. Now Docker displays this in the container memory usage section:


Did you restart WSL after that? Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773629/2123530
